# Text Selection Jumpy When Selecting text in Span with border-bottom

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have noticed an odd behavior with the release of Chrome 77.0.3865 on 2019-09-10.

If I have a span with a border-bottom, this causes a jumpy behavior when you select text. The text selection will jump to the first line when your mouse is above the border.

In the photo below I am currently selecting text, but as you can see the selected text is on the first line.

I am unsure if this is a bug in the recent Chrome release, or if perhaps you are not supposed to add a border to a span (though currently, it's the only way I know to control the span underline thickness).

[image]

Here is a [JSFiddle with the exact code](https://jsfiddle.net/5psgzbqy/3). I can only reproduce this bug on Chrome version 77.0.3865. But it occurs both on Mac and PC computers.

This is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p><span>My first paragraph. My first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraphMy first paragraph.</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS Below

```
p {
  line-height: 31px
}

span {
  border-bottom:2px solid black
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce on  77.0.3865.90, but I've been having a strange, jumpy behavior here on So when trying to select code that did not happen before.

Comment: I wanted to note that this does appear to be fixed in the most recent version of Chrome. I logged it as a bug, and it seemed to have gotten fixed when "FragmentItem" was launched: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1006233#makechanges